# c# function accept integer n and return lowest number that can be divided by divide numbers 1..n

Tags: c#, algorithm, math

I need to write a function that takes as an argument number n and return (as string) the lowest possible number than can be evenly divided  all the numbers from 1 to n.
example if n=4 then the function will return 12 as 12/4 12/3 12/2 12/1 are whole numbers.

i have written a function for that which works fine when numbers are less than 19.. above 19 the computing time is getting much longer.
can someone give me a hint how to better the mechanism for this function to do it quicker

```
 public static string Smallest(int n)
        {
           
            int good = 0;//will hold number of times we got divide with no remianders
            int num = n;//smallest possible number is n
            while (true)
            {
                good = 0;
                for (int i=n; i>=1; i--)
                {
                    if (num % i ==0) good++;//meaning we got zero remainder for the divide
                    if (good == n) return num.ToString();//num of times we got zero remainders == n.

                }
                num++;
            }

        }
```

Comment: First, I'm pretty sure there's an aha experience waiting in the shadows for this one, something about some pattern for the numbers. But, given your existing code, you should try to invert your inner loop, so that if you find a number that it *doesn't* divide into, break early, don't check all the other numbers.

Comment: StackOverflow, techncially, is for broken code - for working code that needs some improvement it mybe more suited to ask on codereview.stackexchange. Just curious, is it not 4x3=12, and 5x4x3=60 as a candidate start etc ?

Comment: There is some sample code [on www.geeksforgeeks.org](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/smallest-number-divisible-first-n-numbers/) that might be helpful.

Comment: This is called the Lowest Common Multiple or LCM.  There is tons of stuff on the internet for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are going to have *huge* numbers for large `n`, that's why let's use `BigInteger` for inner computation.
As Abhishek Pandey put it, we should compute `LCM`, which can be obtained as

```
 LCM(a, b) = a * b / GCD(a, b)
```

where CGD is the Greatest Common Divisor

**Code:**

```
using System.Numerics;

...

public static string Smallest(int n) {
  if (n < 1)
    throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameofn()); 

  BigInteger result = 1;

  for (int i = 1; i <= n; ++i) 
    result = result * i / BigInteger.GreatestCommonDivisor(result, i);

  return result.ToString();
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  using System.Linq;
  using System.Numerics;

  ...

  var demos = string.Join(Environment.NewLine, Enumerable
    .Range(1, 20)
    .Select(n => $"{n,2} : {Smallest(n),20}"));

  Console.WriteLine(demos);
  Console.WriteLine();
  Console.WriteLine(Smallest(100));
```

**Outcome:**

```
 1 :                    1
 2 :                    2
 3 :                    6
 4 :                   12
 5 :                   60
 6 :                   60
 7 :                  420
 8 :                  840
 9 :                 2520
10 :                 2520
11 :                27720
12 :                27720
13 :               360360
14 :               360360
15 :               360360
16 :               720720
17 :             12252240
18 :             12252240
19 :            232792560
20 :            232792560

69720375229712477164533808935312303556800
```

Answer (score 1):

My logic:

1. We take a number - it`s minimal number what can be returned
2. number - 1 - if it can`t divide with no reminder add to n initial n

Don`t forget to update number to initial when 2 step has reminder

Do this until you get correct value

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the LCM (Lowest Common Multiple) of all the numbers from `1 to n`.

Here is a good example to find LCM of an array of elements.
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/lcm-of-given-array-elements/

You can create an array of all the numbers from 1 to n and pass it to this function.

OR

You can modify it to pass only `n` and make it efficient for your use case.